# hortonworks hbase not accessible

Tags: java, hbase, hortonworks-sandbox

I am using centos-release-6-9.el6.12.3.x86_64 in hortonworks sandbox.

I have started hadoop and hbase from ambari server. HMaster and HRegion server started but hquorumpeer is not started.

I am able do all operations correctly on hadoop but while creating table in hbase i am getting following exception:

Hbase table creation

> Exceptionorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   Failed after attempts=35, exceptions: Tue Jan 23 23:06:49 UTC 2018,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@134657b0,
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to find location, tableName=hbase:meta,
>   row=STDVALID_16427ef0-d24f-4605-baa0-1ad1bf27b062,,, reload=false

Can anyone please help on this 
Thanks in advance.